# Why are traits not working?

Tags: php, traits

I am trying to learn traits. I have used the example from PHP manual, but it does not work - why?

```
trait ezcReflectionReturnInfo {
    function getReturnType() { /*1*/ }
    function getReturnDescription() { /*2*/ }
}

class ezcReflectionMethod extends ReflectionMethod {
    use ezcReflectionReturnInfo;

}

class ezcReflectionFunction extends ReflectionFunction {
    use ezcReflectionReturnInfo;

}
```

I get the error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /path/index.php on line 23
```

Comment: Try `echo PHP_VERSION_ID;` If it doesn't output `50400` you don't have PHP 5.4, which means you can't use traits. Further, unless you explicitly installed one of the PHP 5.4 release candidates or manually compiled your PHP version from the trunk SVN repository, you definitely don't have PHP 5.4

Comment: Also, make sure you actually have ezComponentes installed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check your PHP version.

do `echo PHP_VERSION_ID;`

From [Traits:<sup>PHP Manual</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php)

> Traits
>
> As of PHP 5.4.0, PHP implements a method of code reuse called Traits.